# PHP Post - Speical Characters not making it to the server

Tags: php, post, cpanel, whm

I have just migrated a server (WHM / Cpanel) and have set it up "exactly" the same as the old server.

Everything is working fine except for when a user post an odd / special character like "–" via a form field. When this happens the post for that field is set to blank (when I var_dump it out to screen). On the old server and my local testing server it's working fine.

I just can't see why. I've tried changing the character sets via WHM for PHP, but still no joy.

Comment: Thanks! I just transferred it over, looks like the old server had quite a few things commented out for mbstring. In Cpanel/WHM however they looked idential... looks like those changes were not pulling through even after reboot.

Comment: or url_encode the data

Comment: The data wasn't reaching the server at all if it had those characters so I couldn't encode it